# Tkinter StringVar.set within loop not updating at Application level

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI which allows the user to upload the contents of a dataframe into SQL Server by operating on df.iterrows adn executing an INSERT INTO command once a button is clicked. The resulting code loops through the dataframe [pulled in by aggregating several csv files into 1 dataframe] and then loops through each row, inserting that row in the SLQ server table. It works, but I would also like an attached StringVar to update after each row is parsed via the inner loop to tell the user when each row has been processed. The StringVar does not update until the end of the loop i.e the last row is being operated on. I know its something to do with the mainloop being paused while the inner loop is executing but how do I get this to update between rows please? Is this something to with setting a trace of some kind?

I have an example dataframe of 4 rows. self.open_files_create_big_df takes 4 separate csv files and pushes them altogether to form one final 4 row dataframe which I then use self.insert_into_sql to push the data into SQL.

I want the label to show:
"Saving row 1 out of 4..."
"Saving row 2 out of 4..."
"Saving row 3 out of 4... before finally printing:
"Saving row 4 out of 4..."
instead of it currently just showing:
"Saving row 4 out of 4..."
Cut-down code attached. Many thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox
import customtkinter
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import pprint as pp
import xlwings as xw
import pyodbc
import time



class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.notification_label = tk.StringVar(self)
        # configure window
        self.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
        # etc etc
        #deleted code for brevity


        customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, textvariable = self.notification_label
                               ).grid(row=13, column=0, padx=20, pady=(90, 90), sticky=tk.W
                                      )

    def open_files_create_big_df(self, dir_path, sheet_name, rows_to_skip):
        list_dfs = []
        for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
            df = pd.read_excel(dir_path + "\\" + file, sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=rows_to_skip)
            list_dfs.append(df)

        all_dfs = pd.concat(list_dfs)
        return all_dfs

    def get_csv_and_upload_event(self):
        df = self.open_files_create_big_df(dir_path="test directory",
                                      sheet_name="Upload",
                                      rows_to_skip=8)
        self.insert_into_sql(df, servername="ABCDEFG")

    def insert_into_sql(self, df, servername="ABCDEFG", database="Mydb", driver="{SQL Server}",
                        tablename="ManualAdjustments"):
        conn_string = f"""Driver={driver};
                        Server={servername};
                        Database={database};
                        Trusted_Connection=yes"""

        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        counter = 1
        for index, row in df.iterrows():

            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO [{tablename}] ([CurrentMonthEndDateManualEntry],"
                           f"[EventCode],[EventName],[ClaimRef],[ClaimTitle],[LineOfBusiness],"
                           f"[SubLineOfBusiness],[UWY],[CurrentGrossERSIncurredPositive],"
                           f"[CurrentGrossManualPositive],[CurrentGrossAdjustedIncurredPositive],"
                           f"[CurrentCededERSIncurredPositive],[CurrentCededManualPositive],"
                           f"[CurrentCededAdjustedIncurredPositive],[CurrentCededRIPsPositive],[CurrentCededManualPositive2],"
                           f"[CurrentCededAdjustedRIPsPositive],[CurrentNetAdjustedIncurredPositive]) "
                           f"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                           (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6],
                            row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13],
                            row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17]))
            self._notification_string = f"Saving row {counter} out of {df.shape[0]}"
            self.notification_label.set(self._notification_string)

            counter+=1
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `self.update_idletasks()` after updating the variable.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for replying so quickly but unfortunately, adding doesn't cause the interim updates to occur - I also thought that .master may have been missing but that didn't do the trick either. FYI I added self.update_idletasks() immediately after the .set() command

Comment: Then try `self.update()`.

Comment: @acw1668 - my fault, I had an indentation error . That works like a charm, thank you very much for your help.